# Use listbox items in function C#

Tags: c#

I have listed all directories in a folder in a listbox.

```
    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          listBox3.Items.Clear();
          string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\test");

          foreach (string dir in dirs)
          {
            listBox3.Items.Add(dir);
          }
    }
```

How can I list the subdirectories as well? As if it were the command "tree" of the windows command prompt. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a recursive function to dig in all your folders.

like this one.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RecursiveSearch(@"C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\test");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void RecursiveSearch(string dir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
            RecursiveSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```